# Choosing the right field data type in SQL Server 2008

Tags: database-design, sql-server-2008-r2

I got a request to create a new table that will store certain information for customers. The definition of the table is somewhat irrelevant except for one field. This field will store ANSI characters that are retrieved from a terminal screen.

There will be about 50 million rows at first, and initially, we estimated the field will required <= 7,500 characters, so I opted to use the `VARCHAR(8000)` datatype. After more analysis, we determined that probably about 90% of the 30 million rows will be <= 8000, but the other 10% will be <= 15,000.

I obviously can't use the `VARCHAR` due to its 8,000 limit, so I assumed my only option is the `text` datatype. I'm concerned the overhead of 'text' and that it may be removed eventually. I'm now looking at `VARCHAR(max)`, but I've never used it in a production environment.

Should I use `varchar(max)`, `text`, or look for a way to compress that 10% of data and store it in a `varchar(8000)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [`varchar(max)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx). The [`text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx) data type "will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server."

Related on SO [Using varchar(MAX) vs TEXT on SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/834863/569436)

> The basic difference is that a TEXT type will always store the data in
>   a blob whereas the VARCHAR(MAX) type will attempt to store the data
>   directly in the row unless it exceeds the 8k limitation and at that
>   point it stores it in a blob.